# Managing dynamic conditional dependencies with generated state machines?

Tags: node.js, state-machine, directed-acyclic-graphs

Greetings SO denizens!

I'm trying to architect an overhaul of an existing NodeJS application that has outgrown its original design.  The solutions I'm working towards are well beyond my experience.

The system has ~50 unique async tasks defined as various finite state machines which it knows how to perform.  Each task has a required set of parameters to begin execution which may be supplied by interactive prompts, a database or from the results of a previously completed async task.

I have a UI where the user may define a directed graph ("the flow"), specifying which tasks they want to run and the order they want to execute them in with additional properties associated with both the vertices and edges such as extra conditionals to evaluate before calling a child task(s).  This information is stored in a third normal form PostgreSQL database as a "parent + child + property value" configuration which seems to work fairly well.

Because of the sheer number of permutations, conditionals and absurd number of possible points of failure I'm leaning towards expressing "the flow" as a state machine.  I merely have just enough knowledge of graph theory and state machines to implement them but practically zero background.

I think what I'm trying to accomplish is at the flow run time after user input for the root services have been received, is somehow compile the database representation of the graph + properties into a state machine of some variety.

To further complicate the matter in the near future I would like to be able to "pause" a flow, save its state to memory, load it on another worker some time in the future and resume execution.

I think I'm close to a viable solution but if one of you kind souls would take mercy on a blind fool and point me in the right direction I'd be forever in your debt.

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problem few years ago as my bachelor and diploma thesis. I designed a Cascade, an executable structure which forms growing acyclic oriented graph. You can read about it in my paper "[Self-generating Programs – Cascade of the Blocks](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-55032-4_20)".

The basic idea is, that each block has inputs and outputs. Initially some blocks are inserted into the cascade and inputs are connected to outputs of other blocks to form an acyclic graph. When a block is executed, it reads its inputs (cascade will pass values from connected outputs) and then the block sets its outputs. It can also insert additional blocks into the cascade and connect its inputs to outputs of already present blocks. This should be equal to your task starting another task and passing some parameters to it. Alternative to setting output to an value is forwarding a value from another output (in your case waiting for a result of some other task, so it is possible to launch helper sub-tasks).